# How to configure default DISPLAY variable on gdm for x11vnc to work (changed in CentOS 8 from CentOS 7)

Tags: linux, centos, kde, gdm, x11vnc

Problem: GDM/KDE is defaulting to use DISPLAY :1 instead of DISPLAY :0 in CentOS 8, and I want it to use DISPLAY :0 like in CentOS 7. This is affecting x11vnc and causing more of a headache to VNC into the machines (I cannot VNC into the login screen at all now).

**Old/Working Version**

- CentOS 7
- KDE SC Version 4.14.8
- GDM Version 3.28.2

When ssh'ing into old machine to run x11vnc, we can see that :0 is the DISPLAY

```
$ w -us
USER   TTY   FROM  IDLE   WHAT
user   :0    :0    ?xdm?  /bin/sh /usr/bin/startkde
```

**Broken/New Version**

- CentOS Stream 8
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.4
- GDM Version 40.0

When ssh'ing into new machine to run x11vnc, we can see that :1 is the DISPLAY

```
$ w -us
USER   TTY   FROM  IDLE   WHAT
user   :1    :1    ?xdm?  /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session --register-session --run-script /usr/bin/startplasma-x11
user   pts/0 :1   46:05  kded5
```

So now to starting x11vnc in a logged in session on CentOS 8 I need to run `x11vnc -display :1`, which isn't a big deal, just a little annoying and affects some scripts. The bigger issue is that I cannot VNC into the login screen now. Using variations off `ssh -X` `x11vnc -display :1`, running as root, & more.

Both have exact same ssh config (X11 forwarding and stuff).

*Edit:*

Errors when trying to VNC into login screen:

```
~> ssh user@centos8
$ echo $DISPLAY 

$ x11vnc # this works on CentOS 7 w/ and w/o X11 forwarding 
...
10/06/2021 16:28:55 *** XOpenDisplay failed. No -display or DISPLAY.
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key10/06/2021 16:28:59 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
10/06/2021 16:28:59 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key10/06/2021 16:28:59 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
10/06/2021 16:28:59 Trying again with unset XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME ...
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key10/06/2021 16:28:59 
...
10/06/2021 16:28:59 ***************************************
10/06/2021 16:28:59 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:0)
...

$ x11vnc -display :1
10/06/2021 16:30:16 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:1)
$ exit

~> ssh -X user@centos8
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
$ x11vnc
...
10/06/2021 16:24:16 WARNING: DISPLAY starts with localhost: 'localhost:10.0'
10/06/2021 16:24:16 WARNING: Is this an SSH X11 port forwarding?  You most
10/06/2021 16:24:16 WARNING: likely don't want x11vnc to use that DISPLAY.
10/06/2021 16:24:16 WARNING: You probably should supply something
10/06/2021 16:24:16 WARNING: like: -display :0  to access the physical
10/06/2021 16:24:16 WARNING: X display on the machine where x11vnc is running.
...
X11 MIT Shared Memory Attach failed:
  Is your DISPLAY=localhost:10.0 on a remote machine?
  Note:   DISPLAY=localhost:N suggests a SSH X11 redir to a remote machine.
  Suggestion, use: x11vnc -display :0 ... for local display :0

caught X11 error:
10/06/2021 16:24:17 deleted 53 tile_row polling images.
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Serial number of failed request:  56
  Current serial number in output stream:  111

$ x11vnc -display :1 
...
10/06/2021 16:26:16 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:1)
...
```

Similar errors running as root

Comment: *"I cannot VNC into the login screen now."* What is the error you get?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani added edit

Comment: GDM doesn’t run as root, but as the GDM user, and it’s xauth cookies are stored in a gdm-specific directory, so you shouldn’t be able to read them as a regular user.  And if it is running Wayland, it probably won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded from CentOS7 gdm-3.28.2-26.el7.x86_64.rpm and pulseaudio-gdm-hooks-10.0-6.el7_9.x86_64.rpm and installed (downgraded) these two packages on Rocky Linux 8 (8.4) using:
dnf install gdm-3.28.2-26.el7.x86_64.rpm pulseaudio-gdm-hooks-10.0-6.el7_9.x86_64.rpm

gdm in this slightly older version is using "DISPLAY :0" and I can log into login screen using x11vnc.
Not sure what dependencies gdm has and what side effects may occur. Updating OS will reinstall the newer gdm version of Rocky Linux 8 which is using "DISPLAY :1".

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue, really annoying. My brute force solution was just to wrap VNC inside a script, that tries each of :0 and :1 displays. :0 is always the login screen, and :1 is always the gnome session.  So with this, I can VNC into the workstation, log in. Then the VNC session is terminated, i have to restart it, then I can see my desktop. Logging out also kills X, so the VNC session is terminated again.

Something like,

```
(
while true; do
   for displayNum in {0..1} ; do
      if ! pgrep -f "x11vnc -repeat -display" > /dev/null; then

         currentUserId=$(pgrep -x gnome-shell |
                         xargs --no-run-if-empty ps -ho uid |
                         awk '{print $1}')

         x11vnc -repeat -display ":${displayNum}" -rfbport 5900 \
                -shared -auth /run/user/${currentUserId}/gdm/Xauthority \
                -forever
         sleep 0.5
      else
         sleep 10
      fi
   done
done
) &
```